# How do I put this into a function?

Tags: javascript

```
let phrases = [
  'отправить другу смешную гифку',
  'посмотреть скидки на авиабилеты',
  'разобраться, о чём поют рэперы',
  'Юрий Дудь',
  'расставить книги на полке по цвету',
  'читать про зарплаты в Сан-Франциско'
];

let randIndex = Math.random() * phrases.length;
function getRandomElement() {

}
console.log(randIndex);
console.log(phrases[randIndex]);
randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
```

Comment: It's already in a function. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're asking about but took a swing at it.

Comment: What Joel said. The software specification is ambiguous lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let phrases = [
  'отправить другу смешную гифку',
  'посмотреть скидки на авиабилеты',
  'разобраться, о чём поют рэперы',
  'Юрий Дудь',
  'расставить книги на полке по цвету',
  'читать про зарплаты в Сан-Франциско'
];

function getRandomElement() {
  randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
  return phrases[randIndex]
}

console.log(getRandomElement())
```

Edit: Bad copy/paste on my part.

Passing the array as an argument isn't explicitly required so leaving that out. I like to keep as much cruft out of index accessors as I can.

Comment: no need for the `let randIndex` outside of the function.

Comment: No need for `randIndex` at all. Also pass `phrases` as a function parameter.